# Facebook Share in new Window - Don't update SEO

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress

I took follow script for my Facebook Share Buttons:

```
<script>
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' +    descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width=' + winWidth + ',height=' + winHeight);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://www.mywebsite.ch/subsite', 'Fb Share', 'Facebook share popup', 'http://goo.gl/dS52U', 520, 350)">Share</a>
```

My Problem is, if I update any SEO on the sites which are linked, there is no change at all!
If i change the URL, it shows me the new SEO.

It's like there is a Cache or something for this.

My Site (Wordpress):
http://goo.gl/2x2j39

First word: No SEO Update
Second word: Too long Link? Because the Subsite exists

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer...

Put your link in the Facebook Debuger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
Click on "Fetch new scrape information"

And it works fine ;)